# Еще раз о «лосе, который спешил  на водопой»

Tags: вводные-слова

ЛОСЬ ШЕЛ СКАЧКАМИ В СТОРОНУ ОЗЕР, ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ СПЕШИЛ НА ВОДОПОЙ.

1. Считается, что это предложение  с ОДНОРОДНЫМИ СКАЗУЕМЫМИ. Грамматически они, действительно, однородны, так как относятся к одному и тому же подлежащему. Но семантически  (с точки зрения смысла) они не раскрывают общую тему (бежал, спешил)  и, наверное, не должны произноситься с перечислительной интонацией. Автор наблюдает факт (лось скачками бежит), обдумывает его (берет паузу) и далее делает вывод о лосиных намерениях. Но тематику «факт-вывод» обслуживает БСП, тогда у нас получается: ЛОСЬ ШЕЛ СКАЧКАМИ В СТОРОНУ ОЗЕР –  ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ,  СПЕШИЛ НА ВОДОПОЙ. Чем не вариант? Мысль ясная и понятная, вводное слово является вводным словом, и ничем другим.
2. Из Лопатина.  «Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения)».

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Нехорошо нарушать  пока еще действующие и никем не отмененные «Правила орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 года. А там ясно говорится, что вводные слова могут использоваться для присоединения только ОБОСОБЛЕННЫХ (именно уточняющих) членов.

Можно дополнить эту мысль следующим рассуждением: вводные слова в этом случае МЕНЯЮТ СВОЙ СТАТУС и играют роль присоединительных союзов (слова, которые обычно мы воспринимаем в качестве вводных, в различных предложениях могут быть союзом, частицей, обстоятельством). Поэтому нельзя  просто так «отменить» запятую и не обособлять вводное слово, которое ОБЯЗАНО всегда обособляться, – надо что-то сказать об изменении грамматики.

И вообще вся идея отнесения вводных слов к однородным членам и простым предложениям в составе сложного ОЧЕНЬ СОМНИТЕЛЬНА.  На письме запятую просто зачеркнуть, а с интонацией  предложения что делать? Да и вообще можно привести множество примеров, где это правило не соблюдается.

Answer (score 3):

София, я не поняла, это к кому обращён "благородный гнев: "И вообще вся идея отнесения вводных слов к однородным членам и простым предложениям в составе сложного ОЧЕНЬ СОМНИТЕЛЬНА. На письме запятую просто зачеркнуть, а с интонацией предложения что делать?" К Паустовскому? Это ведь его интонация, а не Ваша, и он был вправе поставить запятую там, где считал нужным, - по праву авторства. А мне вот не нравится, когда корректоры начинают править автора и переиздавать книги Паустовского, изменяя его пунктуацию, в современных изданиях можно увидеть уже и с запятой. А по какому праву ? Он разрешал это? Мы и Пушкина начинаем править, его "неправильную"(по нашему мнению) орфографию и пунктуацию, а он не был неграмотным. Это мы неграмотны, не знаем истории языка. Создайте своё произведение и ставьте там запятые, как заблагорассудится, а Паустовского править не надо. У него простой, достаточно гармоничный стиль. И пауза с тире там будет неуместна.Это его незаслуженно забытый  рассказ  «Австралиец со станции Пилево»:" На одном из лесистых островов Кузьма Петрович показал Ване свежие следы лося. Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой. Уже на закате, когда огромное тихое солнце спускалось за океаны осенних лесов, Ваня и Кузьма Петрович поднялись на остров, где лежало пять Боровых озер. От воды тянуло ночной прохладой. Одинокая яркая звезда сверкала над лесами и отражалась в глубине озер". Вполне всё понятно и просто.Зачем усложнять, превращать в БСП авторское простое с однородными членами? Лингвисты должны ИЗУЧАТЬ язык нашей великой литературы,объяснять, а не ПРАВИТЬ.

Я вообще что-то не пойму общий смысл Ваших вопросов. Вы собираетесь реформировать язык? По-моему,современные тенденции языка направлены в сторону простоты и свободы выбора оформления своей мысли среди возможных вариантов, а Вы призываете ужесточить правила, лишить выбора. Зачем? Дух реформаторства обуял? Я с Лопатиным далеко не всегда согласна,но его демократизм мне более по душе. Пунктуация помогает нам передать смысл, идею. А это можно сделать разными способами.Каждый придаёт какой-то свой оттенок,создаёт свой стиль, вот пусть всё так и останется

Comment: Допустим, что я не знаю автора, и просто работаю с предложением. Тогда вы возражаете против моего варианта? Могу его еще упростить для ясности: Человек бежал - должно быть, спешил на поезд. Можно мне так написать, или Лопатин меня поправит?
Реформаторством занимаюсь не я, а именно он, нарушая академические Правила. Наша орфография, отраженная в этих правилах, настолько совершенна, что может обеспечить любую свободу человеку, который знает и понимает грамматические формы языка. А лопатинский демократизм есть не что иное, как лопатинский примитивизм, к которому он нас всех склоняет.

Comment: Против Вашего варианта не возражаю, он тоже имеет право на жизнь,я возражаю против категоричности "нельзя просто так «отменить» запятую и не обособлять вводное слово, которое ОБЯЗАНО всегда обособляться". А менять грамматику много и без нас охотников, пусть академики "отрабатывают свой хлеб". И насчёт примитивизма Лопатина Вы тоже лихо высказались. Вы с ним знакомы? Он просто имеет своё мнение,с которым не все согласны, но если мы не можем его грамотно  опровергнуть, зачем такие оценки? В Академии не дурнее  нас с Вами люди сидят.

Comment: В очередной раз солидарна с Людмилой.

Answer (score 1):

> > Нехорошо нарушать пока еще действующие и никем не отмененные «Правила орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 года. А там ясно говорится, что вводные слова могут использоваться для присоединения только ОБОСОБЛЕННЫХ (именно уточняющих) членов.

Ничего подобного не нашла.

§ 154. Запятыми выделяются слова и группы слов, ограничивающие или уточняющие смысл предыдущих или следующих за ними слов и присоединяемые к ним непосредственно или посредством слов: *в том числе, включая, исключая, за исключением, кроме, именно, по имени*  (по фамилии и т. п.), т*о есть, или*  (в значении «то есть»), *иначе, иначе говоря, например, как например, скажем, как-то, особенно, даже, и притом, и* (в значении «и притом») и т. п.

§ 155. Запятыми выделяются вводные предложения и вводные слова.

> > ЛОСЬ ШЕЛ СКАЧКАМИ В СТОРОНУ ОЗЕР – ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ, СПЕШИЛ НА ВОДОПОЙ. Чем не вариант?

Действительно вариант. Еще Розенталь писал («Пунктуация»):  «Дополнительное тире может подчеркивать причинно-следственные или присоединительные отношения между частями предложения: *Бабушка уже топчется около стола, — должно быть, хочет зажечь огонь*».

> > И вообще вся идея отнесения вводных слов к однородным членам и простым предложениям в составе сложного ОЧЕНЬ СОМНИТЕЛЬНА.

Эта же идея лежит в основе правила о неотделении вводного слова от обособленного оборота. Она предполагает устранение двусмысленности. Только у Розенталя появлялось дополнительное тире, и получалось многовато знаков. Лопатин использовал правило об обособленных оборотах как аналогию и уменьшил количество знаков.
Хотя есть и другая позиция. Авторы «Словаря вводных слов» считают, что в предложении *Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой* «проблемы отнесенности вводного слова к той или иной части предложения на самом деле нет, так как вводное слово обычно стоит в начале или в середине конструкции, к которой относится. А следовательно, слушатель или читатель автоматически относит вводное слово, стоящее на стыке однородных членов предложения или простых предложений в составе сложного, к последующей части предложения». И предлагают или ставить другие знаки, подчеркивающие причинно-следственные отношения (*Лось шел скачками в сторону озер – должно быть, спешил на водопой*), или «данные вводные слова обособлять, как обычно, с двух сторон». То есть *Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть, спешил на водопой*. При этом авторы не отрицают двусмысленность в позиции «вводное слово в начале обособленного оборота», что нелогично.

> > Мне не нравится, когда вводное слово превращают в союз, а называют его по-прежнему вводным словом.

Некоторые вводные слова уже получили этот статус – в том числе и в ПАС Лопатина: «Н*а небе собираются тучи, значит будет дождь* (*значит* — союз)». Но не все вводные слова могут быть союзами.

*tat, я по праву ветерана форума позволил себе провести небольшую техническую правку Вашего ответе для приведение его в соответствие со сложившимся тут стилем. - b-s.*

Answer (score 0):

> Мысль ясная и понятная, вводное слово является вводным словом, и ничем другим.

Самая понятная мысль - принцип бритвы Оккама. Зачем придумывать какие-то странные объяснения, когда есть объяснение естественное?! Грамматика - сама по себе вещь весьма слабо формализуемая, зачем сюда еще и семантику тащить? Ко всему прочему получается ловля кошкиного хвоста. Семантика фразы вытекает из грамматики, вы же пытаетесь грамматику поставить в зависимость от семантики.

> А там ясно говорится, что вводные слова могут использоваться для присоединения только ОБОСОБЛЕННЫХ (именно уточняющих) членов.

Где именно это говорится - и что из этого следует?

Comment: 1. Мне очень нравится работать с толковыми словарями. Находишь любое вводное слово, а там написано, в каких случаях это вводное слово, а  в каких - союз, частица. И мне не нравится, когда вводное слово превращают в союз, а называют его по-прежнему вводным словом.
2. Адрес: Правила орфографии и пунктуации 1956 года, §§ 154 и 155. А следует из этого, что однородные члены - это не уточняющие члены предложения, к которым можно присоединять вводные слова в качестве присоединительных союзов.

Comment: По поводу грамматики-семантики. Я именно и пытаюсь поставить семантику на первое место: смысл должен управлять формой, а не наоборот. Грамматика предоставляет нам своеобразное меню грамматических форм, и я для своего содержания подбираю наиболее удобную.